# Having trouble with cv2.findContours() function

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am unable to find contour and draw a rectangle around it using this video. 
Link: http://www.filedropper.com/outcutscaled

Initially, I tried finding contour by simply using the function `cv2.findContours()` but it was showing some dots. Then i tried applying some morphological transforms but still no luck as contour is not proper.

Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

P.S I am using `cv2.bitwise_and()` to eliminate shadows. One can also use `cv2.bitwise_or()`.

This is my code:

```
import cv2

def diffImg(t0, t1, t2):
  d1 = cv2.absdiff(t2, t1)
  d2 = cv2.absdiff(t1, t0)
  return cv2.bitwise_and(d1, d2)

cam = cv2.VideoCapture('out_cut_scaled.mp4')
fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=50, varThreshold=50)
winName = "Movement Indicator"
cv2.namedWindow(winName, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

# Read three images first:
t_minus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

while True:
  result=diffImg(t_minus, t, t_plus)

  #frame = cv2.resize(result, (20, 20))
  #fgmask = result
  fgmask = cv2.blur(result, (10, 10))
  fgmask = fgbg.apply(fgmask)
  fgmask = cv2.medianBlur(fgmask, 7)



  #ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(result, 127, 255, 0)
  thresh = cv2.dilate(fgmask, None, iterations=2)
  #thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
  """
  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  #cv2.drawContours(thresh, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)


  for contour in contours:
      x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
      if w > 10 and h > 10:
          cv2.rectangle(thresh, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
          print len(contours)
  """
  cv2.imshow(winName, thresh)
  cv2.imshow("frame", t)

  # Read next image
  t_minus = t
  t = t_plus
  t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

  key = cv2.waitKey(10)
  if key == 27:
    cv2.destroyWindow(winName)
    break
```

**OpenCV version: 2.4.13**

**Python version: 2.7**

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

the function `cv2.findContours` modifies the input image and draws the contours as dots in the image. May be that is why you are getting only dots.

To get the complete contours, use `cv2.drawContours` with thickness set to some high value and line type as 8.